# Trigger ID not found with Slack slash command?

Tags: php, slack-dialog

My goal is to be able to use a slash command to open a dialog and process the feedback into a database. I am trying to get the dialog to open but am getting an error regarding the slash command where it says "trigger_id" not found.

- My app is set up with an API and the proper OAuth.
- I added a slash command to my app with the url of my php page (domain.com/slash.php)
- The slash command is set up with the code below.

When I run it from my slack, I get the output of

```
'{"ok":false,"error":"invalid_arguments","response_metadata":{"messages":["[ERROR] missing required field: trigger_id"]}}'
```

I have tried some debugging and output the trigger_id to the screen and find that the trigger_id is indeed null. What am I missing to pass this?

I admit that I am new to the slack realm. I have followed (I think) the documentation from the slack site on setting up the app correctly.

Am I missing something with my slack app setup or something in my code that is causing this error message?

Thank you in advance for your time!

```
<?
$command    = $_POST['command'];
$text       = $_POST['text'];
$token      = $_POST['token'];
$cn         = $_POST['channel_id'];
$user_id    = $_POST['user_id'];
$triggerid  = $_POST['trigger_id'];

// define the dialog for the user (from Slack documentation example)
$dialog = [
    'callback_id' => 'validres-3100',
    'title' => 'Test',
    'submit_label' => 'Submit',
    'elements' => [
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Test Field 1',
            'name' => 'field_1'
        ],
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Test Field 2',
            'name' => 'field_2'
        ]
    ]
];

// define POST query parameters
$query = [
        'token' => '<my api auth code>',
        'dialog' => json_encode($dialog),
        'trigger_id' => $triggerid
];

// define the curl request
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://slack.com/api/dialog.open');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

// set the POST query parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($query));

// execute curl request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// close
curl_close($ch);

var_export($response);
?>
```

Comment: I figured out my issue. My issue was due to my htaccess rewrite that removed the extension. Once I removed the extension from the app settings it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open dialog box in slack you can use this api "https://slack.com/api/views.open".
With api you need to send trigger id which is valid only for 3 seconds.
**Your url will looks like  :**
"https://slack.com/api/views.open?trigger_id=" + "xxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx" + "&view=your data".
with this request you need to send token with your post request like :- 
(URL,"POST", { "token" ,"xoxb-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxx"});

**Need to add view.open API in your slack app also for this use following step:**
Use "Bot User OAuth Access Token" , In "OAuth and permissions Tab" Format is xoxb-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx. And then add scope "views:open" and reinstall your app in slack. And then try to get open view dialog.

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I got the regular dialog to work but would love to use views. Do you have the a snippet of the view definition?

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks. Dont forget to add Bearer before your token